# Возможно ли получить Логин клиента через IChannelInitializer в WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Есть класс `Initializer:IChannelInitializer`, который используется как расширение в app.config.

При подключении нового пользователя к WCF службе, вызывается

```
public void Initialize(IClientChannel channel)
```

Возможно ли вытянуть из `IClientChannel` `WindowsIdentity` и передать экземпляру службы?

Все способы вытягивания `WindowsIdentity`, которые я нашел, основываются на `OperationContext`.

Или подобное поведение реализуется, через жестко заданный порядок вызова операций, где уже в контексте операции я могу взять нужные мне данные?

Answer (score 2):

Нет, нормальным образом его не получить, поскольку инициализация канала срабатывает (может сработать) *до* авторизации.

Но зачем вам передавать `WindowsIdentity` экземпляру службы - если служба и так всегда сможет его получить через `OperationContext`?

Если же вам обязательно требуется передать что-то службе - то вам нужен не `IChannelInitializer` - а `IInstanceProvider`.

```
public MyInstanceProvider : IInstanceProvider {
  public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext) {
    throw new NotSupportedException();
  }

  public object GetInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, Message message)
  {
    var identity = message.Properties.Security.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity;
    return new ВашСервис(identity);
  }

  public void ReleaseInstance(InstanceContext instanceContext, object instance)
  {
    IDisposable disposable = instance as IDisposable;
    if (disposable != null)
    {
        disposable.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```